# Pear PHP UML Class Diagrams

Tags: php, documentation, uml, pear, class-diagram

I am trying to create graphical representations of existing code.  I have tried to use VS.PHP (with Visual Studios 2010) but cant seem to generate class diagrams from this.

I have tried to use Pear's PHP UML package which has produced a lot of JavaDoc style documentation and an XMI document.  From what I have read, this can be used to create class diagrams?  If so, how?

Are there other "easier" alternatives?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/). It has an option to reverse engineer your code.

Comment: I have installed the trial and imported the source directory but I am having a hell of a time working out how to show the class diagrams.  I am sure it something obvious, just getting frustrated!  Any hints?  Thanks

Comment: ah! never mind worked it out. thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Were you able to use PHP_UML for what you needed? I tend to use it with either Umbrello or BOUML with varying levels of success.

Comment: @bigstylee Cool you worked it out. But please, tell others how you did it, too.