# Generate UML from Zend-framework project?

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, uml

Are there any tools for generating UML diagrams from an existing Zend framework project?
Something that detects all classes in specific folders. I don't want the Zend classes to be included because it would become to large and messy, only the classes that I've created...

Any ideas?

I use Netbeans as IDE, so if it's actually possible within Netbeans that would be awesome!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the suggestions in ["PHP: create UML diagrams from source?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237154/php-create-uml-diagrams-from-source), ["PHP UML Generator"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393603/php-uml-generator), or ["Pear PHP UML Class Diagrams"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687493/pear-php-uml-class-diagrams), and maybe other similar SO questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BoUML does the job quite nice with reverse engineering (http://bouml.free.fr/), although I hope I don't need to tell you to make the UML up front